Using on attach on dialog does not let the override method on fragment get called
I am using a dialog that has a click, I want to save the listener of click on "onAttach" from configuration changes, the problem is that it prevents the override method of listener on my fragment to get called. When i click the button the method calls onAttach click, the same thing when the config changes.
I dont want to do it using viewmodel, I just don't know how to fix this, if I remove the click inside the onAttach, still it wont work. Here is my code:
class RedeemGiftCardDialog: DialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: DialogRedeemGiftCardBinding
    var listener: RedeemGiftCardDialogListener? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_Dialog_Alert)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = inflate(inflater, R.layout.dialog_redeem_gift_card)
        dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        return binding.root
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.textFieldCode.editText?.showKeyboard()

        binding.buttonContinue.setOnClickListener {
            val text = binding.textFieldCode.editText?.text.toString()
            if (text.isBlank() || text.length < 6) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Shënoni kodin për të vazhduar!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
            isLoading(true)
            listener?.onRedeemClicked(text)
        }
    }

    fun isLoading(loading: Boolean) {
        binding.buttonContinue.isEnabled = !loading
        binding.progressBar.isVisible = loading
        binding.buttonContinue.text = if (loading) "" else "Aktivizo"
        binding.buttonContinue.hideKeyboard()
    }
}

interface RedeemGiftCardDialogListener {
    fun onRedeemClicked(code: String)
}

//The fragment:


@AndroidEntryPoint
class ProfileFragment : BaseFragment(), ResetBottomSheetListener, RedeemGiftCardDialogListener {
 binding.redeemGiftCardLayout.setOnClickListener {
            val fm = activity?.supportFragmentManager ?: return@setOnClickListener
            val redeemDialog = RedeemGiftCardDialog()
            redeemDialog.listener = this
            if (!redeemDialog.isAdded) {
                redeemDialog.show(fm, redeemDialog.tag)
            }
        }

}

  override fun onRedeemClicked(code: String) {
        Log.d("Dialog","clicked")
       membershipViewModel.activateGift(code)
    }


I am not sure I understood 100% the question. I think you problem is that when the fragments are recreated after config changes the listener is not set in the dialog fragment, and that's why the click listener doesn't work.
Instead of setting the listener, try using fragment result listener as explained in the docs, it will work even after config change:
https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate#fragment-result

No I mean even before the configuration changes the override method on my fragment does not get called when i click the button because the on attach gets called, maybe it creates a new instance of listener so the override method does not get call on my fragment

Oh i just found the bug, its on the "val fm = activity?.supportFragmentManager ", i am showing it on fragment not on activity so it should be childFragmentManager

I see, I didn't understand, sorry. However, setting the listener the way you do is not good, check the link I shared.

Thanks for the suggestion, I will read about it :D
